# Profile service sharepoint 2013 issue

Tags: user-profile

After deleting the service I tried to configure again but it only shows People and about me sittings, and no Newsfeed and tasks and blog and no user activities, any Ideas?

Comment: Please give us a bit more to work on. You deleted the User Profile Service? Then you recreated it. What version of SharePoint? What does the Central Administration Service Application look like? Did you also delete and recreate the My Site Host? What about the personal sites?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had MySites (which contains newsfeed and about me info) configured prior to when you deleted the User Profile, once the UPS is deleted, you have to recreate and configure mysites.

The link between users (in the profile store) and their personal sites are stored in the UPS. That means once they are deleted, the links have also been deleted. You can still access the personal sites using links if you know them (and the my site content DB wasnt deleted), however they are no longer linked.

Short of a [database restore](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e15c75c5-1dd4-49e2-adbd-4bb1bdd6f543/user-profiles-and-mysites-got-deleted-from-sharepoint-2010-site?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) (user profile store, my sites), you may have to recreate my sites (hopefully this is not production!).